# Which Ubuntu package contains the default mouse cursor?

Tags: mouse, cursor

Which Ubuntu package installs/uninstalls the default mouse cursor pointer?

Comment: you mean [these](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cursor&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all) packages ? if I'm not mistaken DMZ cursor is default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you are looking for is `dmz-cursor-theme`. It contains the default mouse cursor for ubuntu.